# Database of welcomeness towards tourists

Tags: data-request, survey, travel

## Context

In order to solve overtourism and generally improve tourists' experience, I want to add to my travel app a feature which suggests alternative destinations where tourists are more welcome.

For instance, a user wanting to climb the Everest would be suggested other mountains that offers the same experience while being more resilient to mass-tourism. A user going to a small Italian village that has become overcrowded due to social networks trending would be suggested similar villages that on the opposite are struggling to attract enough tourists to sustain local activity.

## Need

To measure welcomeness to tourists, I am looking for such databases:

- General opinion of year-long local residents about tourists, ideally as a number from 0 (not welcoming) to 100 (most welcoming).
- How hard the local tourism promotion board is trying to bring tourists, ideally as a number from 0 (not trying to attract tourists) to 100 (trying the hardest).

At village/neighborhood granularity, ideally for the whole world but national databases are OK too.

## Bonus

Bonus if residents opinions statistics are divided into: tourists from the same ethnicity, tourists from the same country, other tourists (in order to track potential racism/xenophobia).

Bonus if promotion board statistics details whether the board wants to increase/decrease some types of tourists in particular (for instance, I have heard that some Hawaii tourism authorities are trying to discourage budget-conscious tourists from visiting).